# Need advice with routing in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, routes, query-string, http-redirect

I'm quite new to symfony2 and I need some help with its routes.

I'm working on a bundle that works quit like a service. It receives data through QUERY_STRING and process this data according to internal rules and store its result in the database. For now, let's assume that this bundle is accessed by this route: http://myhost.com/processing

Calling this service through my computers browser works fine, as it should. So, here comes the problems.

1) The device that access this URL do not understand redirects;
2) I've to mask this URL with something like: http://myhost.com/proc.php, because some devices are with this URL and we cannot change them, so, my service has to be available at this two URLs.

Please, could you give me some advices about this? If you need additional informations, please, let me know.

---

My routes were:

Global routing.yml

```
xx_processing:
  resources: "path/bundle/routing.yml"
  prefix: /proc.php
  options:
    expose: true
```

Bundle routing.yml

```
xx.processing.processing.index:
  pattern: /
  defaults: { _controller: XxProcessingBundle:Processing:index }
```

---

With the configuration above, when my device request http://myhost.com/proc.php?qs, it is redirected to http://myhost.com/proc.php/?qs. After this redirection, the device get lost and the requisition is not processed.

Comment: create 2 routes and link them to the same controller?

Comment: As @WouterJ said, creating a route in Symfony2 is really simple, see [Routing](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html) documentation.

Comment: I've simple routes working, my problem is the redirect issued when the routing occurs. I'll post my route config later on.

Comment: Why do you need redirections?

Comment: My problem was the redirections, after the pointed changes, it worked just fine. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, to avoid the incorrect redirection of my devices request, I've changed the routings as follow:

Global routing.yml

```
xx_processing:
  resources: "path/bundle/routing.yml"
  prefix: /
  options:
    expose: true
```

Bundle routing.yml

```
xx.processing.processing.index:
  pattern: /proc.php
  defaults: { _controller: XxProcessingBundle:Processing:index }
```

---

After change these configurations, there is no more redirection, and http://myhost.com/proc.php is processed successful.